# N+1 problem when not accessed entity's fields which is fetch type Lazy in OneToOne relation

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

My entities:

`

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "employees")
 public class Employee {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private LocalDate birthdate;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
 private Department department;

 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private EmployeeContactInfo employeeContactInfo;

 @CreationTimestamp
 @Column(updatable = false)
 private LocalDateTime createdAt;

 @UpdateTimestamp
 private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
```

}
`

```
@Getter
 @Setter
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "employees_contact_details")
 public class EmployeeContactInfo {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 private String email;
 private String phone;
 private String address;

 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
 @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
 private Employee employee;

 @CreationTimestamp
 @Column(updatable = false)
 private LocalDateTime createdAt;

 @UpdateTimestamp
 private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
```

}

Repository:

```
     @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"department"})
     @Query("SELECT e from Employee e")
     List<Employee> findAllWithDepartment(Pageable pageable);
```

Service:

```
public List<EmployeeCardDTO> getAll(int page, int size) {
        log.info("Action.getAll.start");
        return employeeRepository.findAllWithDepartment(PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by("id")))
                .stream().map(mapper::toEmployeeCardDTO)
                .toList();
    }
```

DTO:

```
public record EmployeeCardDTO(String firstName,
                              String lastName,
                              String department) {
      }
```

Mapper:

```
public EmployeeCardDTO toEmployeeCardDTO(Employee employee) {
        return new EmployeeCardDTO(employee.getFirstName(),
                employee.getLastName(), employee.getDepartment().getName());
    }
```

when i call getAll method i get n+1 problem with my EmployeeContactInfo entity. I use fetchType.Lazy and i don't access fields in EmployeeContactInfo in my mapper. Why i am still facing this n+1 problem. I know i can solve this with adding employeeContactInfo to my EntityGraph but i don't understand why i get this n+1 problem.

Comment: Add your mapping code. Also consider it is an `@OneToOne` IIRC you need bytecode enhancements for that if you want LAZY loading to be effective.